# Mounting CIFS under Docker container does not affect host-mounted volume

Tags: linux, docker, mount, cifs

I'm trying to make a Docker image that logs onto a Kerio VPN and then mounts a remote samba directory onto /mnt.

The mounting is done using `mount -t cifs -o username=USER,password=PWD //ABC/randomDirectory /mnt` and it succeeds. When I list the contents of /mnt from the container itself I can see all the files and directories on the remote server, but when I list the host directory that has been mounted on the container when starting it (`-v /absolute/path/to/mountpoint:/mnt`), it comes up empty.

I tried adding a simple `touch /mnt/test` on the start of the ENTRYPOINT script, and that creates a file in `/absolute/path/to/mountpoint` and is even there when I list it from inside the container. Once I mount the CIFS, listing from inside the container provides all the files and directories on the remote, and listing from the host shows only the created `test` file.

It seems like the `mount` command inside the container "detaches" the docker volume.

**EDIT:** mounting to a subdirectory in the mounted volume doesn't work either

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww <sarcasm>Yeah, because DEVELOPING a Docker image is not development, right..</sarcasm>

Comment: @jww But that was actually useful xD Found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292999/mounting-a-nfs-directory-into-host-volume-that-is-shared-with-docker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The volume can be specified to mount as shared by `-v /local/path:/mnt:shared`